# Setting custom filter in Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, logcat

I have a method to call Log.d that I use throughout an app for debugging. I noticed that there is an Edit Filter Configuration option in the Logcat submenu there which lets me create a custom filter for a specific Log TAG.

[image: menu1]

[image: menu2]

[image: menu3]

Below is the method I use to call the Log.d. I have tried to add it myself but it didn't show them in the Logcat.

```
private static final String TAG = "LOG ENTRY: ";
public void LOG_ENTRY(String what) {
     Log.d(TAG, what);
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement this step by step? Is it also possible to include the error messages in the custom filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by switching the Log Level to verbose and removing the space from the TAG.

```
private static final String TAG = "LOG";
    public void LOG_ENTRY(String what) {
        Log.d(TAG, what);
    }
```

[image: custom filter]

Answer (score 1):

In the attached image (Android Studio "Create New Logcat Filter" dialog) in the question, enter the following values,

Filter name: Any name as per your preference.
In Log Tag field: "LOG ENTRY: " (The Log TAG)(Without the double quotes)
In Package Name: Enter the package name of your application.
In Log Level: Select the "debug" option from the drop-down, since you are using `Log.d` which is for debugging.
PID & Log message fields can be empty.

You can uncheck the regex option in all the 3 checkboxes.

This should let you filter the `logcat` as per your requirement.